# Can't Compile A Simple C Program

Tags: programming, gcc, c

I installed the last version of Ubuntu. I tried to compile and run simple c program. I was get error:

```
fatal error: stdio: No such file or directory
```

I installed and updated gcc compiler few times, and I still get this error. Can anybody help me please?
I put here the video record, there you can see my documents folder with libraries:
http://screencast.com/t/Vi5b7cXnZ

Comment: Could you share what you are trying to compile, what you type when you compile it and what you see after in text rather then a movie?

Comment: Sounds like you don't have the library. Did you install build-essential?

Comment: Though not really unclear--even just in the error message there was enough information to find [the solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/221880/22949)--I suppose we shouldn't reopen this, since it's a programming question that isn't specifically related to Ubuntu. (Writing `stdio.h` as just `stdio` should be expected to produce an error with compilers on other platforms such as Windows, too.)

Answer (score 5):

I looked at your video and saw the problem in your program source. The reason you are getting this error is because you are using:

```
#include <stdio>
#include <stdlib>
```

You should be using:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

..use these corrections in your program and it should now compile.